# Shell script returns 126 exit code from crontab

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, date

Crontab Entry:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * *  /FinalSync.sh $(/bin/date --date="5 days ago" +\%d_\%m_\%Y) || echo $? >> log
```

OR

```
 * * * * *  /FinalSync.sh $(date --date="5 days ago" +\%d_\%m_\%Y) || echo $? >> log
```

Tried both

Got 126 as error code in log file

Shell Script

```
#! /bin/sh

source=/Source/$1
destination=/Destination
folderParam=$(basename $source)
if /usr/bin/rsync -avh -r $source $destination; then
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Success   /Status/Success_$folderParam
else
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Failure   /Status/Failure_$folderParam
fi
```

The result of `ls -l` @ilkkachu

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 299 Oct 17 16:20 /FinalSync.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in my comment on your previous question, error code 126 seems to imply you do not have permission to execute the script or a command inside it (see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html). This is weird though because `crontab` is supposed to be a `root` process. try the following:

```
chmod +x /FinalSync.sh
```

That could help. Otherwise, the problem might come from your `cp` command (maybe you're trying to write somewhere you should not?). Also try `\cp` to avoid aliasing (so that whoever launches the script, it will always behave the same).

Comment: Could be a users crontab though

Comment: I don't think even root can execute a file that doesn't have +x bits.

Comment: @valentin tried this but didn't work

Comment: @HDev007 If your cron is not executed by root, do `chmod a+x /FinalSync.sh` instead. And in any case, verify that `/FinalSync.sh` is executable. Your `ls -l` output shows that it is not.